# How can I start a new row when instantiating UI elements in a grid?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class SavedGamesSlots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject saveSlotPrefab;
    public float gap;
 
    private Transform slots;
    private string[] imagesToLoad;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        int counter = 0;
 
        imagesToLoad = Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath + "/screenshots", "*.png");
        //slots = GameObject.Find("Slots").transform;
        slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.Length; i++)
        {
            var go = Instantiate(saveSlotPrefab);
            go.transform.SetParent(slots);
 
            Texture2D thisTexture = new Texture2D(100, 100); //NOW INSIDE THE FOR LOOP
            string fileName = imagesToLoad[i];
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            thisTexture.LoadImage(bytes);
            thisTexture.name = fileName;
            GameObject ChildGameObject = go.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
            ChildGameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = thisTexture;
            var raw = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
 
            if (counter == 3)
            {
                raw.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(1 , 0.3f, 0);
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                raw.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(1 + counter * gap, 6, 0);
            }
 
            counter++;
        }
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
 
    }
}
```

Now it's creating a line of 3 objects but then when it's filled with 3 objects in a line I want it to move one step down and start a new line of 3 and so on.

The problem is I can't make it automatic move one step down with the right gap on the Y and start a new line.

I'm doing the new line with this :

```
raw.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(1 , 0.3f, 0);
```

but the result is that the fourth object is too much down :

[image: Too much down]

And it should be like this :

[image: In place when starting a new line this is how it should be]

Comment: This looks like a job for the [Grid Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html), so you don't have to write code to manage it at all.

Answer (score 1):

As [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) said in a comment: You don't need to write your own code to calculate and set positions of layout elements in this situation. You almost never need to do that with the Unity UI system. You can leave that job to the [auto layout system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIAutoLayout.html).

In this case the [Grid Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html) seems to be the layouting component of choice. You just set a cell size, and then add child-objects to it. It will arrange its children in cells of the size you picked, and start a new row when it runs out of horizontal space. It even adapts to the screen resolution and uses more or less columns depending on how many pixels it has.